How do I make an object disappear with geometry nodes based on the location of an empty?
I am trying to recreate the effect of the mask modifier where faces gradually and smoothly disappear, but instead of using weight painting i want to use an empty's location to drive that effect.
Like this:

[This is to make it work in a project where there's hundreds of meshes with 100,000 vertices for some objects. So weight painting each and all is out of the question.]
This file is how far i've got as a noob to Geo nodes. The problem here is that the whole geometry is getting deleted at once. I also tried with the "set material" node to a transparent bsdf, but I'm having the same problem as the whole mesh instantly gets the material when the empty is near instead of gradually changing based on the distance to the empty.

Ideally, I want it so that I can use this on whole collections instead of individual objects. But I'll settle for objects too.

Your problem is that you aren't comparing the points position to the position of the empty. Find the distance first, then set a threshold under which GN will know to delete the geometry.

Result:


This is what I wanted! thanks!
Also, is there a way to smoothen the edge faces like in Mask modifier?
I added a gif in the question since i dont know how to link one here.
Also, any possibility to make it work with whole collections?

I just tried it and this is almost what I want. This works based on the proximity to the second object's origin, right? I need to so it works with proximity to the mesh itself (I intend to use a huge plane/cube as the driver).

If you don't want the effect to be based on topology then maybe control alpha in shader instead? Otherwise you need to use boolean mesh to cut the mesh.
